# Binding nested object in ef code first

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

I use Entity Framework Codefirst with Repository and UtinOfWork pattern in winforms application.
How can I bind nested POCO object in winforms datagridview as master/detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common problem developers face with the DataGridView is binding to nested objects. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.developer-corner.com/development/dotnet/datagridview-how-to-bind-nested-objects/) if that is the problem you're having. Another approach is to partial class your objects and create "proxy" properties that just return `SubClass.SubClass.Property` for example.

If that isn't your problem, then here are some general tutorials that should get you started. If you want to update your question with more details we can give a more specific answer.

[Master/Detail forms with DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey.aspx)

[Binding DataGridView to a custom collection](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection)